# How to add Block Into View?

Tags: views

I want to add a block which is created by a view. This block has slider and I need to put between some fields of view.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 15):

There are a few ways to do this.

The simplest is to add your block view to the header or footer of the new view.  To do this, go to the configuration page for the new view and click **Add** next to **Header** or **Footer** (in the middle column).  Choose *Global: View area* and then select your view.

Alternately, for maximum control over layout, you can use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module, but it is much harder to set up.

Another option is the [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.  Here is [a tutorial](http://www.mydrupalexperience.com/view-within-view-fields-module) about how to set this up.

One further option is the [Viewfield](http://drupal.org/project/viewfield) module.

Comment: Thanks Patrick ..I want to add block between two fields so header and footer option will not work ,i do have panel module enable, how to set up this things.

Comment: Ok, if you have a specific placement that you need, you will have to be much more specific.  As far as I know, there is no easy way to insert views within a single view.  You'll need to describe how you created both views and the content types involved.

Comment: My Block view A have body and image fields of content type x,page view B have description and body fields of y content type,I want to add block view A into view B but middle of field description and body field  of content type y.

Comment: Do you know about the Node Reference/Entity Reference modules?  You can often use those modules to get a "view within a view" effect.

Comment: @DilipKale I stumbled across two modules that do what you're asking and a tutorial.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: As far as views in views goes the Views field view module that has been mentioned is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply [Views Block Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_block_area)

> This module exposes all available blocks as a views area or field.
>   This way you can add any block inside a field, footer or header in
>   your view.
>
> Blocks that are generated by views can not be selected, these blocks
>   can not be inserted into views. Add a block as an area
>
> ```
> Go to the view that needs a block inside an area
> Click on add next to header, footer or no result behavior
> Select Global: Block area
> Select the block that you want
> ```
>
> After saving the view, the block will now be visible in the header or
>   footer. Add a block as a field
>
> ```
> Go to the view that needs a block inside a field
> Click on add next to fields
> Select Global: Block area
> Select the block that you want
> ```
>
> After saving the view, the block will now be visible in the view
>   content.