# Create a PDF with one result from a view

Tags: 7, views, files

I have a view with information from a specific database table and I want users to be able to generate a PDF with the results from one row, which would contain all the information from the row. So far, I've only been able to generate a PDF of an entire view instead of one result. I'm not sure how to "tell" the PDF which view result to generate as a PDF.

Note: This is a different way of asking a [question I previously posted](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/244341/create-a-view-from-one-result-of-another-view-and-link-to-it), which I think was too confusing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an idea. You need to create a one more view with same field. But you use views contextual filters and also use view pdf in this view . create a link for print with where you pass argument for this view . Print this link in your first view using view php.

You can also do this custom . create a custom menu item .Pass argument (id,nid) load content programmatically and add pdf download option.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do. How do I pass the argument programmatically and which contextual filters do I use? That's the part I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do.

Comment: I just create a dummy view which is working for node content type basic page please download view from here and import in your drupal setup
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ksugn2j8p5vkg7/view-export.txt?dl=0

Comment: Thank you. What module did you use to get the Global PHP field?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php
Install this module

Comment: I did not getting you point.

Comment: I got this to work with many thanks to you, which is why I gave you a bounty that wasn't originally offered. The only modifications I had to make were installing the views PDF module and creating a pdf view as well as changing the php code and the contextual filter a little bit. Thanks again!